# how can i show an irrational number to 100 decimal places in python?

Tags: python, math, decimal-point

I am trying to find the square root of 2 to 100 decimal places, but it only shows to like 10 by default, how can I change this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module comes in handy.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module for arbitrary precision numbers:

```
import decimal

d2 = decimal.Decimal(2)

# Add a context with an arbitrary precision of 100
dot100 = decimal.Context(prec=100)

print d2.sqrt(dot100)
```

If you need the same kind of ability coupled to speed, there are some other options: [gmpy], [2](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html), [cdecimal](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html).

```
import gmpy2
ctx = gmpy2.get_context()
ctx.precision = 300
print(gmpy2.sqrt(2))
```

Comment: For me was the best solution. By using the library `decimal` also you can get a similar solution but if you want to work with the number (more than just show up in a screen), for me was easier this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sympy and [evalf()](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html)

```
from sympy import sqrt
print(sqrt(2).evalf(101))
```