# Python3 Stop division for large floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, division, integer-division

I am dividing extremely large integers, so to speak up to 1kb integers and I ran into 2 problems already. Either

> OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float

or The float is rounded off to some digits and when I try to multiply back I get a slightly different number.

Is there any way in python to somehow prevent from dividing floats that have more than 20 digits after the decimal point?

```
smallest_floats = []

n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())

while n2 != 1:
  smallest_floats.append(str(n1/n2))
     n2 -= 1
print(min(smallest_floats, key=len))
```

I am thinking that the possible solutions is to somehow assert division or:

```
len(s.split(".")[-1]) > 20
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `decimal` package? Or if you want integer division, what happens if you use `//` instead of `/`?

Comment: Floats in python are the usual 64bit double precision floating point numbers. For what you want to do you need to import a multi-precision package. Scipy or Sympy could have something like that.

Comment: I need to reproduce the number so I need the float number.

Comment: Take a look at the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) package for arithmetic with rational numbers.

Comment: Or you can use `Fraction` to avoid loosing any precision...

Comment: Anybody can provide an answer using Fraction ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you ask python to divide two numbers it will try to do it. What else do you expect?

Comment: That's what I want, I want to know the smallest floating numbers divided by those 2 numbers where the denominator keeps decreasing  @Goyo . as I said I ran into 2 problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rational number arithmetic without precision loss you can use the `fractions.Fraction` class from the [fractions package](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html). You can divide by another rational number and then multiply by it again in order to obtain the very same rational number you had at the beginning.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> n1 = Fraction(large_numerator, denominator)
>>> n2 = n1 / some_rational_number
>>> assert n1 == n2 * some_rational_number
```

Comment: U ended up using Fraction as it was much more effective for my case 95% of the time Fractions where the solution.

Answer (score 1):

import the `decimal` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) it has abritrary precision

you can increase displayed decimal digits with

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573') 100 decimal digits
```

[how can i show an irrational number to 100 decimal places in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733173/how-can-i-show-an-irrational-number-to-100-decimal-places-in-python)

Comment: Not the best tool if the original integer has to be reproduced exactly (although it probably works in most cases). Try the following: `d1 = Decimal(1.0); d2 = d1 / Decimal(3.0); assert d1 == d2 * Decimal(3.0)`. This will raise an `AssertionError` because `d2 * Decimal(3.0)` evaluates to `Decimal('0.9999999999999999999999999999')`. The point here is that `Decimal` provides (almost) arbitrary precision - but not _infinite_ precision.

Comment: @a_guest So Decimal is Not infinitely precise while Fraction is correct? Meaning Using Fraction module I can get the original back?

Comment: @Adminy Yes `Fraction` represents a rational number as numerator and denominator and can thus represent all rational numbers exactly (as long as their nums and denoms fit in memory of course). With the `decimal` module you can select an _arbitrary_ precision which (of course) cannot be _infinite_ (you cannot store an infinite number of decimal places for example). Consider the example `1/3`: `Fraction(1, 3)` is an exact representation while `Decimal(1.0) / Decimal(3.0)` will cut the decimal places after the precision which you've specified.

Comment: I found this answer useful none the less ^^ It helps me too.