# All decimal places [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I am trying to create an E (mathematical constant) approximation script. But it only gives me 15 decimals places. I then added a `Decimal()` which increased the number of decimal places but was still limited to 50 decimal places. Is there any way to print all decimals. (If not, what's the limit?)

---

Here's my code:

```
from decimal import *
e=1
x = input("Iterations:")
x=int(x)
while 1==1:
    e=1 + e/x
    x -= 1
    if (x <= 0):
        break

print(Decimal(e)) # only prints 50 decimal places
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i show an irrational number to 100 decimal places in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733173/how-can-i-show-an-irrational-number-to-100-decimal-places-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting your floating point result to `Decimal` is, of course, not enough.  You have to perform all of the computations using `Decimal` objects and, if you need a large precision, you have to tell `decimal` about that

```
In [73]: from decimal import Decimal, getcontext                                        
In [74]: getcontext().prec = 70                                                         
In [75]: e = Decimal(1)                                                                 
In [76]: x = Decimal(200000)                                                            
In [77]: while x>0: 
    ...:     e = Decimal(1)+e/x 
    ...:     x = x-Decimal(1)                                                           
In [78]: e                                                                              
Out[78]: Decimal('2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076')
In [79]: str(e)[:52]                                                                    
Out[79]: '2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995'
```

Comment: Took a while for my computer to load 10000 digits :D Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try `float64` from [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html). They offer more precision

Comment: No, [almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error).  See also [the reference for numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)